# Distribution of positive semidefinite matrices that are generated by uniformly distributed positive definite matrices

Tags: distributions, sampling, data-transformation, uniform-distribution, cholesky-decomposition

Let $\mathcal{A}=\{ A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n \} \subseteq \mathcal{S}^p_{++}$ be a set of real positive-definite matrices sampled uniformly with a fixed trace (say, using [this algorithm](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6144753)).

To convert each $A_i$ into a positive-semidefinite matrix $B_i$ of rank $k<p$, I want to do Cholesky decomposition $A_i=U^T_iU_i$, set $p-k$ entries of $U_i$ to $0$ and then recompute the trace product.

Is it possible to say anything about the probability distribution of $B_i$? (Say I either compute all $\binom{p}{p-k}$ such positive semidefinite matrices or pick one set of indices uniformly at random among the $\binom{p}{p-k}$ options) Of course, the trace would now change, but I could rescale the matrix $B_i$ to bring it to some fixed trace.